# Codeigniter including Responsive file manager

Tags: responsive-filemanager

I want including Responsive file manager on my CI project (using as Stand-alone file manager).
When I try:

```
$this->load->helper(array('path'));

$this->load->file('filemanager/dialog.php');
```

I have error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare is_really_writable() (previously
>   declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\system\core\Common.php:91) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\filemanager\include\utils.php on line 890

The same error is when I try function include or require. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This errors says your function is already defined ; which can mean :

- you have the same function defined in two files or you have the same
- function defined in two places in the same file or the file in which
- your function is defined is included two times (so, it seems the
  function is defined two times)

*To help with the third point, a solution would be to use include_once instead of include when including your functions.php file -- so it cannot be included more than once.*